# Need to optimise Google Apps Script to reduce script runtime

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've constructed a "Conveyor" style system within Google Sheets to move users from further slots into closer slots when they become available.

Screenshot of the Google Sheets layout where this is being implemented.

[image: Screenshot of the Google Sheets layout]

For example, if someone was in "User 1" but then left, it moves the user in "User 2" into "User 1", the user in "User 3" moves to "User 2", etc., pushing them along the chain, ensuring that the slots are used in order.

As the requirements are time-based, it's often the case that Users 1, 2 and 3 are removed at the same time, meaning that one person is left in the "User 4" slot. Using the current script, it will move them from "User 4" -> "User 3" -> "User 2" -> "User 1".

Additionally, due to some formatting I have set up (Index Matching), I need the cells to display the word "None" instead of staying blank. I've been able to do this easily by checking if the cell is blank, and if so, setting the value to "None".

**The script works, but it is really slow. The total script execution time is over 14 seconds.**

Here's the scripting I'm using:

```
function conveyor() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('UsernameSheet');
  // LOOP 1
  var Username1Val = s.getRange('C3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Val = s.getRange('I3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Val = s.getRange('O3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username4Val = s.getRange('U3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username1 = s.getRange('C3')
  var Username2 = s.getRange('I3')
  var Username3 = s.getRange('O3')
  var Username4 = s.getRange('U3')
  if (Username3Val == 'None') {
    FourtoThree();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2Val == 'None') {
    ThreetoTwo();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username1Val == 'None') {
    TwotoOne();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }

  // LOOP 2    
  var Username1Val = s.getRange('C3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Val = s.getRange('I3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Val = s.getRange('O3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username4Val = s.getRange('U3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username1 = s.getRange('C3')
  var Username2 = s.getRange('I3')
  var Username3 = s.getRange('O3')
  var Username4 = s.getRange('U3')

  if (Username3Val == 'None') {
    FourtoThree();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2Val == 'None') {
    ThreetoTwo();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username1Val == 'None') {
    TwotoOne();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }

  // LOOP 3    
  var Username1Val = s.getRange('C3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Val = s.getRange('I3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Val = s.getRange('O3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username4Val = s.getRange('U3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username1 = s.getRange('C3')
  var Username2 = s.getRange('I3')
  var Username3 = s.getRange('O3')
  var Username4 = s.getRange('U3')

  if (Username3Val == 'None') {
    FourtoThree();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2Val == 'None') {
    ThreetoTwo();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username1Val == 'None') {
    TwotoOne();
  }
  if (Username1.isBlank()) {
    Username1.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username2.isBlank()) {
    Username2.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username3.isBlank()) {
    Username3.setValue('None');
  }
  if (Username4.isBlank()) {
    Username4.setValue('None');
  }
}

function FourtoThree() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('UsernameSheet');
  var Username3Name = s.getRange('O3');
  var Username3NameVal = s.getRange('O3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Start = s.getRange('O4');
  var Username3StartVal = s.getRange('O4').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Finish = s.getRange('O5');
  var Username3FinishVal = s.getRange('O5').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Break = s.getRange('Q7');
  var Username3BreakVal = s.getRange('Q7').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Busy = s.getRange('Q6');
  var Username3BusyVal = s.getRange('Q6').getDisplayValue();

  var Username4Name = s.getRange('U3');
  var Username4NameVal = s.getRange('U3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username4Start = s.getRange('U4');
  var Username4StartVal = s.getRange('U4').getDisplayValue();
  var Username4Finish = s.getRange('U5');
  var Username4FinishVal = s.getRange('U5').getDisplayValue();
  var Username4Break = s.getRange('W7');
  var Username4BreakVal = s.getRange('W7').getDisplayValue();
  var Username4Busy = s.getRange('W6');
  var Username4BusyVal = s.getRange('W6').getDisplayValue();

  Username3Name.setValue(Username4NameVal);
  Username3Start.setValue(Username4StartVal);
  Username3Finish.setValue(Username4FinishVal);
  Username3Break.setValue(Username4BreakVal);
  Username3Busy.setValue(Username4BusyVal);
  Username4Name.clearContent();
  Username4Start.clearContent();
  Username4Finish.clearContent();
  Username4Break.clearContent();
  Username4Busy.clearContent();
}

function ThreetoTwo() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('UsernameSheet');

  var Username2Name = s.getRange('I3');
  var Username2NameVal = s.getRange('I3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Start = s.getRange('I4');
  var Username2StartVal = s.getRange('I4').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Finish = s.getRange('I5');
  var Username2FinishVal = s.getRange('I5').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Break = s.getRange('K7');
  var Username2BreakVal = s.getRange('K7').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Busy = s.getRange('K6');
  var Username2BusyVal = s.getRange('K6').getDisplayValue();

  var Username3Name = s.getRange('O3');
  var Username3NameVal = s.getRange('O3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Start = s.getRange('O4');
  var Username3StartVal = s.getRange('O4').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Finish = s.getRange('O5');
  var Username3FinishVal = s.getRange('O5').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Break = s.getRange('Q7');
  var Username3BreakVal = s.getRange('Q7').getDisplayValue();
  var Username3Busy = s.getRange('Q6');
  var Username3BusyVal = s.getRange('Q6').getDisplayValue();

  Username2Name.setValue(Username3NameVal);
  Username2Start.setValue(Username3StartVal);
  Username2Finish.setValue(Username3FinishVal);
  Username2Break.setValue(Username3BreakVal);
  Username2Busy.setValue(Username3BusyVal);
  Username3Name.clearContent();
  Username3Start.clearContent();
  Username3Finish.clearContent();
  Username3Break.clearContent();
  Username3Busy.clearContent();
}

function TwotoOne() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('UsernameSheet');

  var Username1Name = s.getRange('C3');
  var Username1NameVal = s.getRange('C3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username1Start = s.getRange('C4');
  var Username1StartVal = s.getRange('C4').getDisplayValue();
  var Username1Finish = s.getRange('C5');
  var Username1FinishVal = s.getRange('C5').getDisplayValue();
  var Username1Break = s.getRange('E7');
  var Username1BreakVal = s.getRange('E7').getDisplayValue();
  var Username1Busy = s.getRange('E6');
  var Username1BusyVal = s.getRange('E6').getDisplayValue();

  var Username2Name = s.getRange('I3');
  var Username2NameVal = s.getRange('I3').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Start = s.getRange('I4');
  var Username2StartVal = s.getRange('I4').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Finish = s.getRange('I5');
  var Username2FinishVal = s.getRange('I5').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Break = s.getRange('K7');
  var Username2BreakVal = s.getRange('K7').getDisplayValue();
  var Username2Busy = s.getRange('K6');
  var Username2BusyVal = s.getRange('K6').getDisplayValue();

  Username1Name.setValue(Username2NameVal);
  Username1Start.setValue(Username2StartVal);
  Username1Finish.setValue(Username2FinishVal);
  Username1Break.setValue(Username2BreakVal);
  Username1Busy.setValue(Username2BusyVal);
  Username2Name.clearContent();
  Username2Start.clearContent();
  Username2Finish.clearContent();
  Username2Break.clearContent();
  Username2Busy.clearContent();
}
```

What the script does is Firstly runs to check if the usernames 1-4 have a blank cell. If they do, they set the values to "None".

Then, an IF statement runs to check if Username 3 =  None, if it does, it then runs function FourtoThree, which in itself moves the values from Username 4 to Username 3. It then checks Username 2, then username 1, and does the same type of functions of moving the data along if the value is "None". This whole function then runs 3 times, the maximum number of moves the conveyor system would need to complete.

I'm still a novice with Google Apps Script (well, JavaScript in general), so I threw this together and was happy it worked.

Now, the sluggish runtime of the script is becoming problematic for its use-scenario , and I'm looking for ways to optimize this, please.

> I'm not at all expecting anyone to write me a script that would alleviate my issues, but if anyone could suggest an example of a function that could achieve what I'm trying to do, and/or an idea of how to implement it.

Comment: How do you know if they "left"? Do you just mean is C3 blank?

Comment: Repeated calls to the server using getValue()/setValue() can cause significant performance degradation.  You should try to use getValues()/setValues().  If the data in the range is values and doesn't contain any formulas you could get everything into memory in a 2D array, manipulate the data and then put it back.  with one getValues() and one setValues() call.

Comment: Since you have multiple non overlapping ranges in your script you might want to add ['rangelists'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) to your set of tools.

Comment: Or just get the whole sheet as a array and use only specific values and set it back.

Comment: @J.G. There's another script that checks the time entered by the user in the "Finish Time" box, and compares it to the current time. If it has passed it, it clears all of the boxes for that user. The script automatically removes them at the "Finish time", so that's when they "Leave".

Comment: @TheWizEd - Thanks for confirming! Didn't realise get/setValue() had such an impact. Good to know. Running them under a single ValueS() calls should indeed alleviate that degradation.

Comment: @TheMaster -  I assume you're referring to a similar idea as @.TheWizEd through the use of an array? Or is there another way you'd recommend doing it, please?

Comment: Same as TheWizEd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a prototype you can try but I don't use "None" just blank

```
function conveyor() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Get range C3:W7
  var r = s.getSheetByName('Test').getRange(3,3,5,21);
  var users = r.getValues();
  var formulas = r.getFormulas();
  for( var i=0; i<13; i+=6 ) {  // Only do it 3 times
    if( users[0][i] === "" ) {
      users[0][i] = users[0][i+6];  // Username
      users[0][i+6] = "";
      users[1][i] = users[1][i+6];  // Start time
      users[1][i+6] = "";
      users[2][i] = users[2][i+6];  // Finish time
      users[2][i+6] = "";
      users[3][i+2] = users[3][i+8];  // Busy
      users[3][i+8] = false;
      users[4][i+2] = users[4][i+8];  // Break
      users[4][i+8] = false;
    }
  }
  for( var i=0; i<users.length; i++ ) {
    for( var j=0; j<users[0].length; j++ ) {
      if( formulas[i][j] !== "" ) users[i][j] = formulas[i][j].toString();
    }
  }

  r.setValues(users);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This is brilliant. I've modified the code a little bit to get it working with the sheet, and it does exactly as needed. One question if I may though, please. The cell values where the images are (B6, H6, N6, T6, etc.) apart from the first one (B6) get deleted when the code executes. These cells have a formula in them that changes the image in them using an INDEX(MATCH)  based on the other values (username, and if the True/False boxes are ticked, etc.). This code needs to stay, and not be moved. Is there any way I can do this without the use of more (cont.)

Comment: SetValue() commands to set them back to the set the content of the cells back to the formulas that they should contain after the other script has run? The idea would be for me to cut down on the use of the need for multiple SetValue()'s. I've not used arrays before, and I'm trying to grasp how they work. Can it be done within an array, or would I need to use a different function to get the desired affect, please? Thanks again!

Comment: As we now know there is more in the range C3:W7 then just values.  Maybe share a copy of the spreadsheet so I can see what's there?

Comment: I've modified my prototype to handle formulas.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I've checked it, and it works beautifully. The rest of the cells were just plain strings. It was just the image cells that use the following formula to identify which image to display: =if(E7=TRUE,(INDEX('Nesquik 2.0'!$E:$E,MATCH("Break",'Nesquik 2.0'!$A:$A,0))),if(E6=TRUE,(INDEX('Nesquik 2.0'!$E:$E,MATCH("Busy",'Nesquik 2.0'!$A:$A,0))),if((or(C3="",C3="None")),(INDEX('Nesquik 2.0'!$E:$E,MATCH("None",'Nesquik 2.0'!$A:$A,0))),(INDEX('Nesquik 2.0'!$E:$E,MATCH(C3,'Nesquik 2.0'!$A:$A,0))))))

(Forgive the sheet name, ha). Thank you so much for the help.